# Creating pluggable database using dbca

Tags: oracle

I have created a PDB using Database Configuration Assistant.Is there a way I can look at where the data files got created? I did not get the option in DBCA to specify my data file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't this [what you asked earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33832730/266304), and got an answer to?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the options:

Connect to the CDB and query `cdb_data_files` and `cdb_pdbs` data dictionary views

```
select file_name
  from cdb_data_files cdf
       join cdb_pdbs p
          on (cdf.con_id = p.con_id)
where p.pdb_name = '<container_name>'
```

**Note**: `cdb_pdbs` data dictionary view doesn't show root container - only pdbs associated with the current cdb. If there is a need to see all pdbs including cdb query `v$containers`view.

Answer (score 0):

The below query list all the datafiles and you can see the datafiles related to pdb with pdb name in their path.

Select name from v$datafile